# Autodesk forge translation error: Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741852

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are getting the below error when trying to translate a Creo file. (ZIP file upload to OSS, translated through model derivative)

Can't find any info on what a "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741852" error is. Can anyone help point me in the right direction to diagnose the issue?

```
    {
    "urn": "XXXXXXXX",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "name": "XXXXXXX.asm.1",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741852",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf",
            "status": "failed"
        }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "failed"
}
```

Comment: Please show the request body, for complex files, you need to mention rootfile name and it should be in the right place, you can check this example: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#example-2

Comment: Hi Varunpatil, shouldn't be any issue with how the file is sent up. We've translated 1000s of models using our system and forge. We are just looking for more information on this specific error code so we can hopefully correct the model being translated if the issue lays with it

Comment: It could be related to translation engine, will contact our engineering team and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, our engineering team has requested for the file to debug. is it possible for you to mail it to forge.help@autodesk.com?